# EOF is sent prematurely using "fgetc"

Tags: c, stream, eof, fgetc

I am writing a program that prints out the Firefox `cookies.sqlite` file.

```
int printfile(FILE* cookiesfile)
{
    int c;
    //fseek(cookiesfile,0x18260,SEEK_SET);
    do{
        c=fgetc(cookiesfile);
        printf("%c",c);
    }while(c != EOF);
    printf("\n\n%x",c);
    if (ferror(cookiesfile) != 0)printf("\nchareror!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The code returns `EOF` at various points before the end of the file. Opening the file in a hex editor or notepad shows that the file is much larger. The `EOF` always appears at the same points. Skipping past these points, data is read until the next `EOF`. Characters that the `EOF` occurs on have often been fgot previously without any problem (i.e. `0x1a`, `0x13`).

Checking the result from `ferror()` does not help (as no error is present).

I am not sure how to proceed in my debugging process, can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, it may not. fgetc would not return -1 in that case. (though you could get the appearance that it did if you assign the return value of fgetc to a char instead of an int)

Comment: Use `feof` to read a binary file .I have modify my code, Since I don't  have you file , hope you can try my code. and give me a result.

Comment: As a general tip, don't read a binary file as it were a text file. The results will be undefined.

Comment: thanks, yes i used fread() instead in the end it was much better suited to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how you opened the file, we can't say for sure, but SQLite database files are not text files. If you open a SQLite database file in text mode on a Windows machine, you're going to be receiving EOF every time you try to read at a location that contains a value of `26` (`0x1A`, <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>) <sub>(and there's no reason to assume that such locations will remain stationary)</sub>. There are a number of free (and commercial) tools for dealing with SQLite database files, not least of which is the [SQLite Manager plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) for FireFox itself. If you still want to do it in C, I recommend that you go to [the SQLite website](http://www.sqlite.org/), download the code, and read the introductions and documentation.

Comment: thanks, yes i abandoned this approach for this reason and because it is extremely inefficient. Instead I used fread, which was a much better solution.